# Общий класс для Assembly-CSharp-Editor и Assembly-CSharp

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Всем привет! Есть код для редактора в котором по шаблону через меню в самом редакторе по нажатии кнопки собирается ассет по дочернему классу ScriptableObject собирается он в Assembly-CSharp-Editor, соответственно дочерний класс ScriptableObject находится там же. В сборке Assembly-CSharp есть точно такой же дочерний класс но ассет собранный по классу из Assembly-CSharp-Editor не подходит для Assembly-CSharp.

Comment: Пока что нашел решение писать код для редактора в той же сборке что и скрипты для игры

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под "не подходит"? И если вы собираетесь использовать объект вне редактора, то почему вы создаёте его класс в редакторе?

Comment: @M.Green при перетаскивание ассета в переменную для него он не вставляется, у меня 2 одинаковых класса 1 для редактора что бы собирать через меню 1 для игры что бы работать с ним код 1 и тот же но ассет собранный по классу из пространства редактора не встает в пустую переменную под точно такой же класс но уже созданый в пространстве игры

Comment: Потому что это не такой же класс. Пространство имён тоже считается частью имени. Я не совсем понимаю зачем вам отдельный класс под редактор. Вы можете использовать в редакторе класс из "игры".

Comment: @M.Green  просто хотелось бы хранить весь класс для редактора в папке Editor

Comment: классы редакторы - это скорее классы "расширения функционала редактора". Т.е. у вас есть базовый класс, который вы используете в игре. Но если в редакторе вы хотите рисовать его каким-то особенным образом - вы пишете для него кастомный редактор) Вот и храните "класс редактора" в папке Editor.

Comment: @M.Green я это знаю но дело в том что из класса расширения функционала в данном случае меню я  не могу собрать ассет из класса ScriptableObject не лежащем в папке Editor

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "собрать ассет"?

Comment: @M.Green http://priscree.ru/img/3333ca8b460e77.jpg это класс который не лежит в папке Editor спокойно собирается через контекстное меню в проекте и появляется ассет http://priscree.ru/img/081ac388badb19.jpg 
так же у меня есть меню в папке Editor в этом меню есть кнопка которая собирает ассет этим кодом http://priscree.ru/img/b62d87ae71cce5.jpg но меню не видит класс потому что оно находится в другой сборке

Comment: Что значит "у меня есть меню в папке Editor"? Что значит "меню не видит класс"? Из класса лежащего в папке Editor, вы спокойно можете создать новый ассет, класс которого относится к основному проекту. В последнем случае вы привели код, который сохраняет в виде ассета новый экземпляр класса-скрипт объекта. В нём нет никаких ошибок и он должен работать.

Comment: @M.Green вот в том то и дело что я не могу создать класс лежащий в основном проекте через класс лежащий в папке Editor

Comment: Ну, а я вам гарантирую, что создать можете и приведённый вами метод на последнем скрине прекрасно с этим справится) в итоге мы докопались до вашей основной проблемы - теперь опишите, в чем именно проблема при создании. Удалите ваш CharacterSettings, который лежит в папке Editor - какая ошибка у вас появилась? "не удалось найти имя или пространство имён"? Установите каретку на строку с ошибкой и нажмите Ctrl + . (или ПКМ на ошибку и "Быстрые действия и рефакторинг") вижуалка предложит вам список действий, среди которых будет добавление using с нужным вам namespace, если это возможно

Comment: @M.Green так, только что закинул все менюшки в папку Editor и вдруг класс меню увидел класс для сборки ассета, думаю это из-за того что раньше класс для ассета был полностью сериализованным, а сейчас только некоторые параметры, спасибо за вашу помощь!